# Let $G$ be a group of prime order $p$. Then $|\operatorname{Aut}(G)|=p-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $p$ where $p$ is a prime number( hence, $G$ is cyclic ) Prove that the group of automorphisms of $G$ has order $p-1$.

Since $p$ is prime, for any homomorphism $\phi: G \to G$ the orders or $g$ and $\phi(g)$ are the same.

Moreover, obviously, $|S_G| = p!$. Since $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is a subgroup of $S_G$, $|\mkern-3mu\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$ must divide $p!$.

Comment: Hint: An automorphism is uniquely determined by the image of a generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A group of order $p$ is cyclic, isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$. An endomorphism of this group is defined by the (arbitrary) image $g^k\enspace (0\le k\le p-1)$ of a generator $g$, and it's an automorphism if and only if this image is a generator. This is the case if and only if $k$ is prime to $p$, i.e. if and only if $1\le k\le p-1$ since $p$ is prime. Hence
$$\lvert\operatorname{Aut}G\rvert=p-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi$ is an automorphism then $\phi(g)$, where $g$ is the generator, can be $g^1,\dots, g^{p-1}$ (it wouldn't be an automorphism if you sent it to $e$) then you can get $\phi(g^n)$ for all $n$ by $\phi(g^n)=\phi(g)\cdots\phi(g)$.

So there are only $p-1$ options.

Answer (score 0):

Since $G$ is cyclic, $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. It is a fact that $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \cong U(n)$ for all $n$, where $U(n)$ is the group of units under multiplication mod $n$. Hence $Aut(G) \cong U(p)$ and $|U(p)| = p -1$.